# Would initialising a character array from a string literal be a case of array copy initialisation?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, literals

I had always thought it fine to, in my mind, replace any use of a literal with a temporary variable of that literal's type and value. If this *is* the case, since string literals are of type array of const char would initialising a character array through a string literal not be considered array copy-initialisation? E.g. wouldn't

```
const char test1[] = "hello";
```

be somewhat the same as doing...

```
const char temp[6] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};
const char test2[] = temp;
```

which would be forbidden since this is an example of array copy initialisation? How is it that string literals can be used to initialise an array if the literal's type *is* an array? Maybe somewhat related, if string literals are of type array of const char then how is it the following code seems to compile fine on my system?

```
char* test3 = "hello";
```

Since test3 is missing low-level const the compiler misses this unlawful conversion, but it compiles fine anyway? Of course trying to change any element through test3 causes the program to crash.

Comment: Are two things that fail to compile "considered the same"?

Comment: @juanchopanza only if the errors are the same, I think. :)

Comment: @juanchopanza Well the first line I had entered incorrectly. But the second code producing an error was kind of the point of my question. I've edited my post to be a little clearer.

Comment: Keep in mind that that the type of a string literal is an array of characters, so `const char test1[] = "hello"` isn't taking a copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between copy or direct-initialization for arrays. Both cases are handled identically by the compiler. The analogy you make in the beginning is more of a rule of thumb. In reality, an array cannot be initialized by another array unless it is a string literal. BTW your analogy is not entirely correct. The target array would be direct-initialized with the temporary array:

```
const char test2[](test1);
```

But this still won't compile for the same reason. This is how initialization of a character array works.

[dcl.init]/p17:

> The semantics of initializers are as follows. The *destination type* is the type of the object or reference being initialized and the *source type* is the type of the initializer expression. If the initializer is not a single (possibly parenthesized) expression, the source type is not defined.
>
> - If the initializer is a (non-parenthesized) *braced-init-list*, the object or reference is list-initialized (8.5.4).
> - If the destination type is a reference type, see 8.5.3.
> - **If the destination type is an array of characters, an array of `char16_t`, an array of `char32_t`, or an array of `wchar_t`, and the initializer is a string literal, see 8.5.2.**

8.5.2:

> An array of narrow character type (3.9.1), `char16_t` array, `char32_t` array, or `wchar_t` array can be initialized by a narrow string literal, `char16_t` string literal, `char32_t` string literal, or wide string literal,
>   respectively, or by an appropriately-typed string literal enclosed in braces (2.13.5). Successive characters of the value of the string literal initialize the elements of the array. *[ Example:*
>
> ```
> char msg[] = "Syntax error on line %s\n";
> ```
>
> shows a character array whose members are initialized with a *string-literal*. [..]

In your other example the string literal decays into a pointer to its first element, with which `test3` is initialized. This code is invalid in C++11<sup>1</sup>, as the decayed pointer is `const char*`, but this was a valid conversion in C because string literals were non-const. It was allowed in until C++03 where it was deprecated.

---

<sub>1: Some compilers still allow the conversion in C++11 as an extension.</sub>